# [Chart.js]How can I prevent my chart from drawing beyond it's min time?

Tags: javascript, time, max, chart.js, min

I have a line chart with minimum and maximum values on the XAxes time scale. I also have a dropdown menu for the user to display the last week, last two weeks, last three weeks, last month, etc. Evertime the user selects one of those date ranges, I update the min and max time of my x scale. The problem is that the data doesn't start to be displayed at the min value, it starts drawing beyond that like you can see in the picture.

[image: This is how it looks normaly with the complete time range]

[image: this is how it looks with the time range "last month"]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a chart.js way to solve this problem, so I had to change the datasets myself. When selecting a date range, I now remove all the elements that are outside of this scope and then update the chart.